# Routing example.com/page to example.com:[port]

Tags: networking, server, services, routing

I have a server with multiple services running, for example:

```
subdomain.example.com:1234
subdomain.example.com:1235
subdomain.example.com/1236
```

Accessing these directly will take me to the web gui for these services.

i want to set the server up so that I can, for example, go to:

```
subdomain.example.com/service
```

and it will access the web gui at:

```
subdomain.example.com:1234
```

What do I use to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use an apache server as a kind of portal for you services ? 
I would use mod_rewrite and mod_proxy to makes internal proxy request to the service

with rewrite rules like

```
RewriteRule ^service1/   http://servername:1234  [P]
RewriteRule ^service2/   http://servername:1235  [P]
RewriteRule ^service3/   http://servername:1236  [P]
```

see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

In the directory you wish to have a redirect, create a file named .htaccess and put the following line of code in it:

```
Redirect  /service  subdomain.example.com:1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DNS for that type of redirect. The SRV record type is used exactly for that. Look up RFC 2782 - A DNS RR for specifying the location of services (DNS SRV) and also [help.dnsmadeeasy.com/records/srv-record](http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/records/srv-record)

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskUbuntu, please elaborate about the method and how to solve the asker question.